# Prevent OnItemProcessed event occuring for more than once per publish based on condition

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

I have below situation where, I have to prevent OnItemProcessed event from occuring more than once.

```
namespace Website
{
    public class ItemEventHandler
    {
        public void OnItemProcessed(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            // Code here will be processed once for every item in that publish event.



            if(condition){
            Queue.WriteMessage();
            }

            // once message is written to Queue based on condition, this event handler should not be run for subsequent items in that publish event
        }
    }
}
```

events config patch

```
<sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="publish:itemProcessed">
        <handler type="Website.ItemEventHandler, Website" method="OnItemProcessed">
        </handler>
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
```

Comment: Is your event handler configured to run on `item:published` event? So you want to write to Queue only for the first item published? E.g. you publish item with 2 children, and you want to write to Queue only for the parent item, not for the children, correct?

Comment: @MarekMusielak.. the event handler is configured on "publish:itemProcessed". For ex I have 10 items in particular publish event, and on 5th item, condition is satisfied and message is written to queue, it should not process the event handler for subsequent items(i.e 6-10)

Comment: Try to add a public static bool variable in the `ItemEventHandler` class, and set it to `true` when the condition is satisfied. Then add another event handler on `publish:end` which will reset the variable back to `false`. It should do the trick assuming that you have only 1 Sitecore instance publishing items at the same time and you're not using publishing service.

Comment: don't forget to let us know if this solution worked for you

Comment: sure @MarekMusielak

Comment: @MarekMusielak .. sorry for the delay in replying.. it worked for me.

Comment: excellent! I converted my comment into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `public static bool` variable in the `ItemEventHandler class and set it to`true when the condition is satisfied.

Then add another event handler on `publish:end` which will reset the variable back to `false`.

It will do the trick assuming that you have only 1 Sitecore instance publishing items at the same time and you're not using publishing service.